# sliding captions: can't get div to perfectly match image

Tags: css, sliding, captions

I've been searching but haven't found an answer for the specific problem I'm having.

I wanted to use sliding captions for the images on my art blog. The challenge was that I needed the container to adapt to variable image heights so I didn't have to go in and set it manually every time I post something new. What I have so far is really close to working but...

The div is 5 pixels bigger than the image, regardless of the image's height. I made the div background red so it's easy to see the overlap, but I just can't figure out where those 5 pixels are coming from.

I'm really new at this and changed all the css values I could think of and searched for other examples but I still couldn't get the overlap to go away. Any help would be awesome. I'm so close (I think) but I don't know what else to try. Here's most of the css with a jsfiddle link below:

```
/* variable container adapts to image size (plus 5 unwanted pixels) */
/* I made the background red so you can see where it's too big */
div#imgContainer {
    min-width: 20px;
    min-height: 20px;
    display:inline-block;
    background:red;
}

.postContainer {
position:relative;
overflow:hidden;
background: red;
}

.postContainer .postTextbox {
width:100%;
height:50px;
position:absolute;
bottom:0;
left:0;
margin-bottom:-15%;
margin-left:auto;
margin-right:auto;
opacity: 0;
border:0px;
background: black;
}

.postContainer:hover .postTextbox {
margin-bottom:0;
opacity: 1;
}

.postTextbox {
-webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease;
transition: all 0.3s ease;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/nun243j1/

Thanks again in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It may be because of white-space between elements. Apply `image {display: block;}` for images to remove this problem.

Comment: Beautiful! I don't have enough reputation to upvote you or I would. Because I only want to apply this to posted images what's the best way to implement this? I did `#imgCap {display: block;}` and then tagged the image with `id="imgCap"`. Is that a good way to go?

Comment: @andyV It's better to apply it more dynamically with `.postContainer img{display: block;}` (DON'T use same ID for all elements, ID must be unique per page). And you can accept answer to get reputation.